# Error Code: 1172. Result consisted of more than one row in mysql

Tags: mysql

my code is returning an error Error Code: 1172. Result consisted of more than one row
when I run following code:

```
delimiter //
create function purchase_status(customernumber int) returns varchar(100) reads sql data
begin
    declare purchase_state varchar(100);
    select 
        case
            when amount < 25000 then "Silver" 
            when amount between 25000 and 50000 then "Gold"
            else "Platinum"
        end as purchase_state2 into purchase_state
    from payments;
    return purchase_status;
end//

#drop function purchase_status;

select customernumber,customername,purchase_status(customernumber) as purchase_status
from customers;
```

i didnt get how to call it..

Answer (score 0):

The `Select` clause inside the function must return one row if you use **`into purchase_state`**.

You probably forgot about the `WHERE` clause on `customernumber` or `SUM(amount)` instead of amount.

Example:

```sql
select 
  case
    when SUM(amount) < 25000 then "Silver" 
    when SUM(amount) between 25000 and 50000 then "Gold"
    else "Platinum"
  end as purchase_state2 into purchase_state
from payments WHERE customernumber = customernumber
```